# nginx server location route

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

Its my nginx configuration file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name san.cashbaba.com.bd www.san.cashbaba.com.bd;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

its now working perfectly . my requirement is if anyone write in browser address bar **san.cashbaba.com.bd/admin** then another application open which already store in **/usr/share/nginx/html/adminApp** folder .

anyone help me how to write this configuration in this config file

Comment: What is in `/usr/share/nginx/html/adminApp` folder? html/css/js files or something else?

Comment: @RichardSmith my another project in AdminApp folder. I want if i write mydomain/AdminApp then this application open

Answer (score 0):

You can specify another location block like that, nginx will apply the most concrete match on each request.

```
location /admin {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/adminApp
    index index.html index.htm;
}
```

The official doc [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html) and a good document form Linode [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx/)